# Facebook API - Sharing Activity

Tags: android, facebook

Good day!

I am currently developing a security application that once activates, will automatically get the GPS, send it via SMS, take a photo and then share it through Facebook. I was able to do a simple sharing activity but I'm having trouble automating the Facebook sharing without it showing the preview of the post. The content posted will be inputted by the user so it's not breaking Facebook API regulations. I know that this is possible since some mobile games implement them. Any kind of help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it some days back like this.....

```
imageview_fbshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Util.isDeviceOnline(MainActivity.this)) {
                Util.showProDialog(MainActivity.this,"Please wait....");

            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                lastimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                // params.putString("caption", etxt_status.getText().toString());
                //params.putString("place", user_loc_id);
                //params.putString("tags", ids);
                params.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);

                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/" + user_id + "/photos",
                        params,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                //new getPlaceId().execute();
                                JSONObject o = response.getJSONObject();
                                try {
                                    String user_status_id = o.getString("id");

                                } catch (Exception ex) {

                                }

                                Util.dimissProDialog();


                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"OOps! Network Connection Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The line imageview_fbshare cannot be resolved. I cant seem to make this work

Comment: it is just the simple imageview on click of which i shared the image on facebook, you can simply put this inside any onclick of button etc

Comment: Is Util.isDeviceOnline part of Facebook API? Cant seem to resolve it.

Comment: No its not the part of it, i used it to check that the internet connection is active before hitting the network request

Comment: are you able to share image on facebook now